# How to separate key-values per row from a JSON formatted list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've been trying to get a more readable output from a JSON list. I have not yet been successful. I hard-coded some data to see if I can get it as I want. This is what I did:

```
import json

jsonData = {
    "person": {"FirstName": "Kwin", "LastName": "Harley", "Age": 25},
    "DoB": {"DateOfBirth": "19/12/1996", "Birthplace": "Belgium"},
    "insurer":{"id":"12345","contractNumber":"98765432",
               "valid_from":"2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","valid_until":"2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "representativeID":"135792468",
               "representativeEmail":"sample@test.com"}

}
jsonString = json.dumps(jsonData, sort_keys=False, indent=4)

print(jsonString)
```

### Output 1

[image]

As you can see, the data is structured nicely.

Now, when I use my main code, the output looks like this:

### Output 2

[image]

It just returns the data in 1 row :(

Is there a way to fix that? This is the code I have for that:

```
qrType = qr.type
qrData = json.dumps(qr.data.decode('utf-8'),sort_keys=True)


# print the QR type and data to the terminal
print("[INFORMATION] Found {} barcode:\n{}".format(qrType, qrData))
```

Comment: What is `qr` in your code?

Comment: `code` 
for qr in barcodes:
    # extract the bounding box location of the barcode and draw the
    # bounding box surrounding the barcode on the image
    # this isn't necessary. It just shows you where the QR is found
    (x, y, w, h) = qr.rect
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 150, 0), 3)
Basically to loop around the qr code to draw rectangles around a QR code. But I don't need to have the rest of the code in the for loop, to be honest.

Comment: if you have to `.decode()` qr.data, presumably it's a string.  In which case you first need to *parse* it as json, and then you can dumps it.  note `indent=2` in the `dumps` will format nicely

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm sorry @martineau :(

Comment: @2e0byo :o This actually made a lot of sense! I added the following code after 'qrData':

`code` parsedData = (json.loads(qrData))
qrJason = json.dumps(parsedData, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

Now it looks proper! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're passing a dict to `json.dumps()` at all.  `qr.data` is clearly a string, as you `.decode()` it.  Presumably it's a json string, so you want to do something like this:

```py
formatted_data = json.dumps(json.load(qr.data.decode()), indent=2)
print(formatted_data)
```

Comment: Yea. Ugh. Can't believe I missed this! I think I now did the same as you did, but with an extra line of code ^^